# Select one row from a range of rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've come across a very interesting problem.. quite lost actually. Suppose I have a table with range of values, like:

```
id.........From........To
1..........0...........5
2..........6...........10
3..........11...........15
4..........16...........29
```

So now I have an integer say @MyInt = 8, I want to select that single row in which this integer lies in. In this example, 8 comes between 6 and 10 so it should select row id=2

I obviously cant do

```
select * from table where From < @MyInt AND To >= @MyInt
```

because it will select all rows, since all the numbers will be lesser and/or greater..

So how do I select that single row in a situation like this?

Many Thanks!

Comment: I dont need the exact querry, I quite like challenges, so even if you guys can tell me the basic idea of how to go about select this.. would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM TABLE t
 WHERE @MyInt BETWEEN t.[from] AND t.to
```

...works because both criteria ***on a per row basis*** need to be satisfied to return the row - it's equivalent to:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM TABLE t
 WHERE @MyInt <= t.to 
   AND @MyInt >= t.[from]
```

...which is fine, because the values are exclusive sets.  BETWEEN is ANSI standard, and always inclusive - Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite will all return the same data (assuming similar data type).

If you used:

```
AND @MyInt > t.[from]
```

...you'd never capture rows where your variable is identical to the `from` value (IE: 0, 6, 11, 16).

Comment: um... Your comparisons are backwards. It should be t.from <= @MyInt <= t.to

Comment: +1 - to be even more explicit the BETWEEN operator is always inclusive of the range given

Answer (score 2):

The statement you suggest should work fine:

```
select * from table where From < @MyInt AND To >= @MyInt
```

I think you are confusing AND with UNION:

```
select * from table where From < @MyInt
UNION
select * from table where To >= @MyInt
```

will give you all the rows, however, your statement will give you only the rows (row) that satisfies both conditions.

(Actually, it will miss the case where @MyInt equals the lower bound.  It should be:

```
select * from table where From <= @MyInt AND  @MyInt <= To
```

I also reverse a condition, so the relationship is more obvious)

Comment: +1: For a query that would return the values the OP expects to see, though their actual query would not.